# Composition vs inheritance (how to understand Thinking in Java)

Tags: java, inheritance

Could you help me understand what is written below. This is from Thinking in Java book.

> Because you are composing a new class from existing classes, this
>   concept is called composition(if the composition happens dynamically,
>   it's usually called aggregation).
>
> Composition is often referred to as a "has-a" relationship, as in "A
>   car has an  engine."
>
> Composition comes with a great deal of flexibility. The member objects
>   of  your new class are typically private, making them inaccessible to
>   the client  programmers who are using the class. This allows you to
>   change those  members without disturbing existing client code. You can
>   also change the  member objects at runtime, to dynamically change the
>   behavior of your  program. Inheritance, which is described next, does
>   not have this flexibility  since the compiler must place compile-time
>   restrictions on classes created  with inheritance.
>
> Because inheritance is so important in object-oriented programming, it
>   is  often highly emphasized, and the new programmer can get the idea
>   that  inheritance should be used everywhere. This can result in
>   awkward and  overly complicated designs. Instead, you should first
>   look to composition  when creating new classes, since it is simpler
>   and more flexible.

Without examples I can't grab this jelly. Could you provide me with examples of:

1. **Aggregation**, that is composition happening dynamically.
2. **Inheritance** facing compile-time restrictions.

I mean that I'm looking for examples revealing advantages of composition over inheritance.

Added later: I need examples of code (not description).

Comment: This is not a good question for the SO format as there are too many possible answers. About your second question: if "Car extends Engine" than you cannot change the implementation of the engine anymore at runtime, so you don't have the flexibility to replace the default `Engine` with a `V6Engine` or an `ElectricEngine`. You would need another `V6Car extends V6Engine` etc. which is not very flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mean that I'm looking for examples revealing advantages of composition over inheritance.

Let's say you have a top-level abstraction `AbstractCar`. If you were to create an strong inheritance relationship, you have something like

```
abstract class AbstractCar {
    protected abstract void startEngine();
}

class FastCar extends AbstractCar {
    @Override
    public void startEngine() {
        System.out.println("turn key... vroom");
    }
}
```

As far as functionality is concerned, this looks like it fits the bill, as a car should have the functionality of starting an engine. But what if you wanted to switch out the engine or install push-start functionality to the engine. You would have to change the implementation.

A better approach would be to extract the engine functionality to an `Engine` class and encapsulate *that* into the `AbstractCar`. `Engine` would be a top-level abstraction whose implementation could change, and you would be able to to use the `Engine` as the type while allowing the engine implementation to change. For example

```
interface Engine {
    void startEngine();
} 

class PushStartEngine implements Engine {
    @Override
    public void startEngine() {
        System.out.println("push button.. vrooom");
    }
}

abstract class AbstractCar {
    protected Engine engine;
    protected void setEngine(Engine engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }
    protected void getEngine() {
        return engine;
    }
}

class FastCar extends AbstractCar {
    public FastCar() {
        setEngine(new KeyStartEngine());
    }
}
```

This may not be the best example (as it still imposes tight type coupling - there are other design patterns to fix that), but it should give you an example of the advantages of composition over inheritance. The basic premise to to extract what varies, in this case the Engine. In a string inheritance relationship, you would probably have more functionality defined in the top level abstraction, but when you favor composition of inheritance, you encapsulate that functionality into other objects. This allows for easier extensibility and change.

So with the example above, you can now easily switch out the engine, which would not be possible in the case of inheritance

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // let's say you have another OlderCar implmentation
    // that has a KeyStartEngine
    OlderCar car = new OlderCar();
    car.getEngine().startEngine();

    // I just hit the lotto, lets upgrade!
    PushStartEngine engine = store.buyPushStartEngine();
    car.setEngine(engine);
    car.getEngine().startEngine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a great example:

- Composition: a university is a *composition* of departments (and other static fixtures).
- Aggregation: a department has an *aggregation* of professors: they may come and go, and even be associated with a different department (at another university)

A discussion of *inheritance* in comparison to *composition* would take too long here. Let's just say that inheritance is good for representing

- refinement: add more and different properties as per subclass, resulting in different sets of features or capabilities
- abstraction: you realize that a group of things have some properties or features in common, which you "factor out" into a base class
- variation: A group of things have identical features but the "inner working" of these features is different and require different implementations, which would be put into different subclasses

Expressing different features by composing various components makes sense if these components can be used in various ways, or are already available, or the number of possible compositions cannot be easily expressed by a type hierarchy. Also, consider that a composition of *abstractly* typed components opens up a wide range of combination when *actually* composing the root object, using different implementations (subclasses) of those abstract components.

Lots of articles available on the net discuss this fundamental topic. Here is one [article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076814/core-java/inheritance-versus-composition--which-one-should-you-choose-.html). Note that in software design there is no rule that's good in every case, so be prepared to use more than one design principle...

Comment: I have more or less understood what was meant. But to better understand it I just need examples of code, not description.

Comment: What about using a search engine? This is just one srticle: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076814/core-java/inheritance-versus-composition--which-one-should-you-choose-.html